# Standard Python wrapper to turn f(x) into f(*x)?

Tags: python, functools

I keep coming across use cases for the following wrapper:

```
def asterisk(fn):
   def retfn(x):
      return fn(*x)
   return retfn
```

Is there something in the standard Python 2 library that already does this? I had a look in `functools`, but couldn't find anything.

For context, here is a recent use case:

```
print map(asterisk(operator.sub), [[-20, 20], [-20, 20], [32, 32]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To provide this:

```
print map(asterisk(operator.sub), [[-20, 20], [-20, 20], [32, 32]])
```

You should use

```
from itertools import starmap
print starmap(operator.sub, [[-20, 20], [-20, 20], [32, 32]])
```

P.S. As far as I know, there is no built-in functions for such functionality in Python. Some time ago, I talked in Python mailing list about lack of "apply" functionality, which is more "general" questions. I think, something like `operator.apply(f, args)` will be good for many cases. This functional representation for function application can also except argument about arguments passing model.

Comment: (+1) You, sir, are a star :-)

Comment: I think `apply()` used to exist, but it was removed due to the fact that the star operator does the same job. Why would you ever need it?

Answer (score 1):

While `starmap` is a good solution for some cases, another option here, which I feel is far more readable in this case, is to use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) instead:

```
[x - y for x, y in [[-20, 20], [-20, 20], [32, 32]]
```

I would recommend that you use a list comprehension (or generator expression) as soon as you find yourself using the `operator` module or `lambda`s, as it will result in far more readable (and often faster) code.

Comment: That's true. The example I chose isn't great. I wanted it to be simple, and ended up with something that is trivially rewritten using a list comprehension. :)

Comment: @NPE My argument is there are very few cases where a list comprehension isn't a better option. Something like constructing vectors from tuples might be a good case for `starmap`, but in general, it's not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really necessary, because for any callable `f`, you can write:

```
lambda *args: f(*args)
```

Which does what you need. The syntax is shorter than any library call. It's only if you need to reify the transformation itself that you need that, but then writing that is as simple as writing:

```
def starify(f):
    return lambda *args: f(*args)
```